# Unreal Engine 4 -- Stop "Random Point in Bounding Box" to return Negative values on X,Y,Z direction

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

I'm trying to drop characters inside a box at random points using "Random Point in Bounding Box" in Unreal Engine 4.19 blueprint .

[image: Negative values return]

But the problem is that this function is throwing some "Negative" values on the return which are causing to generate characters below the box. Any solution how to avoid that negative values on X, Y, Z direction or turn them into positive values so that these weird below-growing things just get solved? I'm new in UE4, so kindly pardon my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

did you get this working yet? right click on the return value of any of the nodes that return a vector, and this will expose the x,y,z they are returning. you can check if the number is negative to change it to what ever you want, such as for example, if value<0, then value=value*-1, etc, etc. hope that helps.